# How to count when using list of data

Tags: python

```
test = "aaaabbcdeiiifkdkkffkk"
search = ["a", "c", "d", "e"]
data = test.count(search)
data
```

When I run this, I get

> TypeError: must be str, not list

I want to know how I can count when using `[ ]` instead of a single string.

Comment: Try using loops

Comment: The string count() method returns the number of occurrences of a substring in the given string.  Are you trying to get the count of each letter in the list?   If so you need to loop through the list. If instead, you are trying to get the count of search as a string you need to convert the list to a string first using join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a loop on search

`data = [test.count(s) for s in search]`

Answer (score 1):

`count()` takes a `str` parameter and not a `list`.

```
test = "aaaabbcdeiiifkdkkffkk"
data = test.count("a")
```

More info [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/count).

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop throught the search list, so this list comprehension can do the job:

```
[test.count(i) for i in search]
```

But i prefer this

```
test = "aaaabbcdeiiifkdkkffkk"
search = ["a", "c", "d", "e"]

data = {}
for i in search:
    data.update({i: test.count(i)})
```

Or you can use a one liner.

```
data = {c: test.count(c) for c in search}

Out: {'a': 4, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple ways to find out, to count the number of occurrence, `.count()` only takes one `str` value

**Method 1: Using List Comprehension**

`data = [test.count(s) for s in search]`

**Method 2: Using Map**

`data = list(map(test.count,search))`

You can create multiple other methods to do so referring the above.

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.Counter`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter

test = "aaaabbcdeiiifkdkkffkk"
search = ["a", "c", "d", "e"]
count_data = Counter(test)     #--> Counter({'k': 5, 'a': 4, 'i': 3, 'f': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 2, 'c': 1, 'e': 1})
for i in search:
    print(i, count_data.get(i, 0))
```

**Output:**

```
a 4
c 1
d 2
e 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over search strings and apply count to each one.

```
data = []
pos = 0
for s in search:
    data[pos] = test.count(s)
    pos = pos + 1
print(data)
```